# Converting UTC Time to DateTime Object

Tags: c#, .net

I have a UTC time string which I needs to convert in Datetime Object in C#.

I have tried the below sample, but its not working. Can any one help?

```
long ticks = long.Parse(ateOn);
DateTime ateOnDate = new DateTime(ticks,DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

where ateOn is UTC time in string.

Comment: What is a "UTC time string"? What does it look like? Are you talking about Unix epoch time?

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? Please be specific. What happens exactly.

Comment: 1360417399227, yes i am talking about epoch time

Comment: it gives me {1/2/0001 1:47:21 PM} date when i tried it with above code and put 1360417399227 in ateOn

Answer (score 1):

```
long l = 1360417399227;
var dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
         .Add(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(l));
```

Comment: You got my vote. It would be useful for Samee Mir to explain why you add milliseconds and not seconds (in case of l = 1360417399) as he's confused with datetime ticks and epoch time.